# Projection issues Landsat 5 in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, landsat, wgs84

I'm using an image of Landsat 5 in QGIS and even though I fix the projection to WGS84 EPS: 4326 using Raster tool Warp. The projection is out of focus. I normally work with Landsat 8 and never had this issue before. Any idea how to fix the projection?

Comment: What is the problem when you add the original (unwarped) raster to QGIS?

Answer (score 0):

Your Landsat product may be badly georeferenced. If "L1GS" or "L1GT" appear in the name of your product, then its geolocation is degraded. It happens when:

> In some cases (and more likely in older Landsat data), scene and/or sensor issues, or insufficient reference data can cause L1TP processing to fail. Scene issues include snow, ice, and clouds, which prevent an accurate registration of GCPs within a scene. Sensor issues include measurement/outliers in the spacecraft or instrument telemetry of an interval which also affect the usability of the GCPs. In these scenarios, a L1GT or a L1GS product will be created instead.

See the different processing levels here: https://www.usgs.gov/landsat-missions/landsat-levels-processing